# Skype application layer protocol

Tags: peer-to-peer

what is skype protocol layer on the application layer. I know skype is not client /server . it is peer to peer. But I want to know what is its application layer protocol? I try wireshark to know that. But is just shows me TCP on Transport layer.

Comment: Are you trying to block skype on an network or what is the intention?

Comment: yes I want to find some way to black its connection

Comment: Should be a hard task to accompish because skype uses random tcp ports between 1024 and 65000 and it even is able to use port 80 or 443 if you make the right configuration. Is it a home or a company network you need to block somehow skype?

Comment: You might try this http://pingtool.org/block-skype-connection/ but not sure if it works.